# Why can't my Azure Function find Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.Proxy assembly dependencies?

Tags: azure, proxy, dynamics-crm

I'm using Azure Functions and want to write code that reads/writes to Dynamics CRM. I added the CRM SDK DLLs (all of them) to a bin folder.

Some code lines are below

```
r"D:\home\site\wwwroot\TimerTriggerDaily\bin\Work365.Microsoft.Store.PatnerCenter.Manager.dll"
r"D:\home\site\wwwroot\TimerTriggerDaily\bin\Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling.PackageDeployment.CrmPackageExtentionBase.dll"
r"D:\home\site\wwwroot\TimerTriggerDaily\bin\Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.Proxy.dll"
```

---

```
using Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.Proxy;
```

When running the function I get this error:

```
Exception while executing function: Functions.CrmTest1.
mscorlib: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

2017-06-13T06:07:58.840 Function started (Id=fb308e51-5e92-4405-8915-2ad34fd5505f)
2017-06-13T06:07:58.840 Function compilation error
2017-06-13T06:07:58.840 (29,25): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Proxy' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.Crm.Sdk' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
2017-06-13T06:07:58.840 Function completed (Failure, Id=fb308e51-5e92-4405-8915-2ad34fd5505f, Duration=1ms)
2017-06-13T06:07:58.871 Exception while executing function: Functions.TimerTriggerDaily. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script: Script compilation failed.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to create a project.json file in the righthand pane (View Files -> Add) and paste this json into it:

```
{
  "frameworks": {
     "net46":{
       "dependencies": {
           "Microsoft.CrmSdk.CoreAssemblies": "8.2.0.2"
        }
     }
  }
}
```

You can replace the CoreAssemblies and version number with the packages you need, put all three of them in the dependencies node.

Comment: Hi Ziya, could you flag this as answer or reply if it's still not working for you?